# how get data url from json?

Tags: java, android

I have Button for open link this code

```
public class Settings_d extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Settings_d );


        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new8);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = "https://www.google.com";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want update url some time without update app .. 
How get data url from JSON ?

Thanks

Comment: Explain more please.

Comment: some time i want change url : https://www.google.com to other url without update app ... i thank can do this by JSON

Answer (score 0):

You dont need JSON.

> JSON, or JavaScript Object Notation, is a minimal, readable format for
>   structuring data. It is used primarily to transmit data between a
>   server and web application, as an alternative to XML. Squarespace uses
>   JSON to store and organize site content created with the CMS. [Read more](https://developers.squarespace.com/what-is-json/)

You can use webview like this:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/webView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

So , try below codes to change url in your button:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

You can see more webview plugins in [here.](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/230?sort=created)

Comment: No.. some time i want change url : google.com to other url without update app

Comment: You have to use an server, something like firebase will be good for you

Comment: You cant change url of another activity from another app,you have not permission to do it. try to use a webview inside your app to change url. Your question is realy Unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change some data in your app try to use [onesignal](https://onesignal.com) . It is a free push notification panel , and you can send background data by it to your app,and you can do anything in background service inestead of displaying notification.
[Read more](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding).